# SharePoint 2013 workflow help

Tags: 2013, workflow, infopath

I’m relatively new to workflows and need some help please with SharePoint 2013?

The requirement is as follows:-

Users will add list items via an InfoPath form. This item will also include the selection of a specific user from a SharePoint group who will be the approver
The new list item will trigger a workflow & send an email to the approver
I want the approver to review the item & either approve or reject with the ability to add comments. 
I also want to remove all fields from the task apart from Approve/Reject, Title (linked to item), creator of the list item & a comments section. 
This is the main part I’m stuck on & I’ve tried many ways to get this to work.
I’ll be using the 2013 WF. How, I’ve tried to get this to work is simply hiding the unnecessary columns but the approval seems to base itself on being either complete or on the status (& not the Approve/Reject).

& finally an email sent to the creator with notification of approval/rejection along with the comments.

It’s also worth mentioned that I do not want to use content approval as the solution as I’d like to expand upon the workflow at a later date.

Image of what I've achieved so far.

[image]

Many thanks in advance for any help & guidance, John

Answer (score 1):

task forms are auto-generated based upon a certain Content Type, to customize the task form you'll need to create and customize a new workflow tasks contents type as i explain in the below steps

**1. Create a Custom workflow task content type**

Navigate to

```
Site Settings - under Web Designer Galleries - Site content types - Create
```

[image]

Under parent Content Type, choose `List Content Types` in Select parent content type from
And `Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)` in Parent Content Type

[image]

**2. Add the content Type to your Tasks List**

After creating the new workflow task content type you need to add it to your tasks list
Navigate to `Site Contents - Tasks (Yours tasks list)` , is this example I’ll use the default tasks List .
Open the `List Settings - under the Contents Types - Add from existing site content type`
Select your custom contents type click add then `OK`.

[image]

**3. Modifying the new content type view**

Navigate to `Site Settings - under Web Designer Galleries - Site content types`
Click on the new content type `(MyCustomTaskContentType)`

[image]

Select the column you need to hide

[image]

Under the `Column Settings - Select Hidden (Will not appear in forms)` then `OK`

[image]

**4. Assign the Content Type to your designer workflow Start a Task Process and Assign a Task actions**

In the `Start a Task Process` or `Assign a Task` , you should define the `Task Content Type` in the `outcome options` to the new content type.

Comment: Thank you. I've followed your advice but stuck on the final bit whereby I define the Task Content Type in the outcome options to the new content type. Can you elaborate further please?

Comment: Note. I have set my new content type against the 'ContentTypeId' in the 'Start a task process Properties'. A task is created. When I Approve or Reject the workflow shows cancelled with a deleted association & a subsequent instance of the workflow is started showing activity in progress?? Any idea?

Comment: @Johno deleted association problem usually appear when you previously  delete a workflow , is that the case with you?

Comment: @A.Sayéed. Yes, I had a couple of previous attempts at building the workflow & decided to delete it along with the workflow task list & start afresh. Do you have any advice to remedy the issue please?

Comment: @Johno from your list go to Settings - Workflow Settings- click on" Remove, Block, or Restore a Workflow" & check for the deleted workflows if they still showing up